# asp.net mvc5 , raw sql : Display data in Views generated using aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using ASP.NET MVC, EF and SQL Server 2014.

I want to generate a view which would show total sick leave and annual leave an employee with employee id. I found a LINQ query very complicated and I don't know how to use it in Asp.net MVC. I wrote a controller for this purpose and now I have no idea how to display this data in the view.

Please help me with this. If there is better way of doing this or if I am making mistakes, please let me know.

SQL queries are below:

```
SELECT 
    [EmployeeId], SUM(AssignedLeaveDay) AS Total_Annual_Leave    
FROM 
    AssignLeaves 
WHERE
    [EmployeeId] = 1 AND LeaveTypeId = 4
GROUP BY 
    [EmployeeId]

SELECT 
    [EmployeeId], SUM(AssignedLeaveDay) AS Total_Sick_Leave    
FROM 
    AssignLeaves 
WHERE
   [EmployeeId] = 1 AND LeaveTypeId = 5
GROUP BY 
   [EmployeeId]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh5iW.png)

Comment: You can use viewmodel properties, `ExecuteReader` & `DataTable` to show results in view, can you show view code & controller action example for doing so?

Comment: I just want to display these two records from database in view that's all i want to know how to retrieve data from database using aggregate function with EF ASP.Net EntityFramework and show it in view

Comment: You want to display this query result in view?

Comment: Yes i want to display this code in view

Answer (score 0):

//Controller side
 var Data = from data in AssignLeaves.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == 1 && s.LeaveTypeId  == 4)
                                   group data by data.EmployeeId into g
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       EmployeeId = g.Key,
                                       Total_Annual_Leave = g.Sum(x => x.AssignedLeaveDay)
                                   };

var SickLeaveData = from data in AssignLeaves.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == 1 && s.LeaveTypeId  == 5)
                                   group data by data.EmployeeId into g
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       EmployeeId = g.Key,
                                          Total_Sick_Leave = g.Sum(x =>
 x.AssignedLeaveDay)
                                   };

You get Total Annual leave by:  Data.FirstOrDefault().Total_Annual_Leave ;
You get Total_Sick_Leave  by:   SickLeaveData.FirstOrDefault().Total_Sick_Leave;

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need complete the asp.net mvc cod i mean how to code in  publick Actionresult index () which model or viewmodel should i pass to index view